Howler.js web app experiencing intermittent audio cutoff after prolonged runtime on Windows 11 and Brave browser
I created a simple white noise web app that uses Howler.js (not configured to use HTML5 audio player) for audio looping. It works great and I keep my computer running with this simple powershell script:
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

while (1) {
    $wsh.SendKeys('+{F15}')
    Start-Sleep -seconds 59
}

I'm experiencing a problem where the audio will cut off after what seems like a couple days of running (the timing seems inconsistent). Interestingly, the browser volume/audio indicator shows that audio is still playing from the tab but I have to switch the sound off/on within the web app (a series of pause and play calls to Howlers.js) for it to start again.

I use the Brave browser Version 1.65.126 and am on Windows 11 Home 23H2 22631.3447. I'm unable to find anything regarding a feature of the Windows operating or chromium that would cause audio to cut off after a certain amount of time. My speakers are fairly old and are just hardwired as there's no wireless capability which makes me think they aren't the culprit.
Any ideas what could be causing the audio to cut off after running for a couple days without issues?

It could be a lot of things, maybe a power settings parameter (advanced settings in the current profile), maybe a soundcard parameter (go to control panel/sound, and control panel/device manager/audio-video-game controller), maybe a sound card specific application/setting, maybe the browser (try another one), maybe your speakers (try another pair). On a another note, noise pollution is a thing, listening to white noise 24/7 could lead to tinnitis/permanent hearing loss, watch out.
